# DevExpress: Get filtered rows from a GridControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, devexpress

this is a difficult question to explain, but I'm trying because I'm really stuck and I don't know how to solve my issue.

I've a gridControl of devExpress in my xaml. It is populated with a observableCollection in the mvvm pattern design. In this gridControl I have also a battery of filters, correctly working.

I need the content of the gridControl filtered, as the user see it. I have found a way to this, with a working sample.

But... I get always ALL the records, not only the visible ones.

I have this in the code behind of my xaml:

```
public interface ICustomGridControlService
{
    IList GetAllFilteredAndSortedRows();
}

public class CustomGridControlService : ServiceBase, ICustomGridControlService
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataControlProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("DataControl", typeof(GridControl), typeof(CustomGridControlService), new PropertyMetadata(null));
    public GridControl DataControl
    {
        get { return (GridControl)GetValue(DataControlProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DataControlProperty, value); }
    }
    public IList GetAllFilteredAndSortedRows()
    {
        return DataControl.DataController.GetAllFilteredAndSortedRows();
    }
}
```

and this in my viewModel:

```
ICustomGridControlService CustomGridControlService { get { return GetService<ICustomGridControlService>(); } }
public ICommand GetAllFilteredAndSortedRowsCommand { get; private set; }
```

and this is the xaml of the gridControl

```
<dxg:GridControl x:Name="dgrErog" ItemsSource="{Binding ListaMonitorErogazioni2}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedArchivioErogazioni}" >
    <dxg:GridControl.TotalSummary>
        <dxg:GridSummaryItem FieldName="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=Codice}" SummaryType="Count" DisplayFormat="Records: {0}"/>
        <dxg:GridSummaryItem FieldName="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=Litri}" SummaryType="Sum" DisplayFormat="Tot.: {0}"/>
        <dxg:GridSummaryItem FieldName="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=PU}" SummaryType="Average" DisplayFormat="P. medio: {0:c2}"/>
        <dxg:GridSummaryItem FieldName="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=Importo}" SummaryType="Sum" DisplayFormat="Tot.: {0}"/>
    </dxg:GridControl.TotalSummary>
    <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
        <dxg:GridColumn x:Name="ID" Binding="{Binding ID}" FieldName="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=Codice}" AllowEditing="False"/>
        <dxg:GridColumn Binding="{Binding TRAN_ID}" FieldName="N° tran." AllowEditing="False"/>
        <dxg:GridColumn Binding="{Binding IMPIANTO}" FieldName="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=Impianto}" AllowEditing="False">
            <dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                <dxe:ComboBoxEditSettings 
                    NullText="" FilterCondition="Contains"
                    AllowNullInput="True"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window},Path=DataContext.sListImpianti}"
                    IsTextEditable="True">
                </dxe:ComboBoxEditSettings>
            </dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
        </dxg:GridColumn>
        <dxg:GridColumn Binding="{Binding DATA_EROG}" FieldName="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=Data}" AllowEditing="False"/>
        <dxg:GridColumn Binding="{Binding IDVEI}" FieldName="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=Veicolo}" AllowEditing="False" >
            <dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                <dxe:ComboBoxEditSettings 
                    NullText="" FilterCondition="Contains"
                    AllowNullInput="True"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window},Path=DataContext.sListVeicoli}"
                    IsTextEditable="True">
                </dxe:ComboBoxEditSettings>
            </dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
        </dxg:GridColumn>
        <dxg:GridColumn Binding="{Binding IDTEV}" FieldName="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=TesseraV}" AllowEditing="False">
            <dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                <dxe:ComboBoxEditSettings NullText="" FilterCondition="Contains" AllowNullInput="True" IsTextEditable="True"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window},Path=DataContext.sListTessereV}"/>
            </dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
        </dxg:GridColumn>
        <dxg:GridColumn Binding="{Binding IDGRV}" FieldName="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=GruppoV}" AllowEditing="False">
            <dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                <dxe:ComboBoxEditSettings NullText="" FilterCondition="Contains" AllowNullInput="True" IsTextEditable="True"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window},Path=DataContext.sListGruppiV}"/>
            </dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
        </dxg:GridColumn>
        <dxg:GridColumn Binding="{Binding IDAUT}" FieldName="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=Autista}" AllowEditing="False">
            <dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                <dxe:ComboBoxEditSettings NullText="" FilterCondition="Contains" AllowNullInput="True" IsTextEditable="True"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window},Path=DataContext.sListAutisti}"/>
            </dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
        </dxg:GridColumn>
        <dxg:GridColumn Binding="{Binding IDTEA}" FieldName="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=TesseraA}" AllowEditing="False">
            <dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                <dxe:ComboBoxEditSettings NullText="" FilterCondition="Contains" AllowNullInput="True" IsTextEditable="True"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window},Path=DataContext.sListTessereA}"/>
            </dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
        </dxg:GridColumn>
        <dxg:GridColumn Binding="{Binding IDGRA}" FieldName="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=GruppoA}" AllowEditing="False">
            <dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                <dxe:ComboBoxEditSettings NullText="" FilterCondition="Contains" AllowNullInput="True" IsTextEditable="True"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window},Path=DataContext.sListGruppiA}"/>
            </dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
        </dxg:GridColumn>
        <dxg:GridColumn Binding="{Binding IDPRO}" FieldName="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=Prodotto}" AllowEditing="False">
            <dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                <dxe:ComboBoxEditSettings NullText="" IsTextEditable="True" FilterCondition="Contains" AllowNullInput="True"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window},Path=DataContext.sListProdotti}"/>
            </dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
        </dxg:GridColumn>
        <dxg:GridColumn Binding="{Binding IDERO}" FieldName="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=Erogatore}" AllowEditing="False"/>
        <dxg:GridColumn Binding="{Binding VOLUME_LT}" FieldName="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=Litri}" AllowEditing="False"/>
        <dxg:GridColumn Binding="{Binding KMATTUALI}" FieldName="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=Km}" AllowEditing="False"/>
        <dxg:GridColumn Binding="{Binding PRUNIT}" FieldName="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=PU}" AllowEditing="False" >
            <dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                <dxe:TextEditSettings Mask="c" MaskType="Numeric" MaskCulture="eu" MaskUseAsDisplayFormat="True" />
            </dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
        </dxg:GridColumn>
        <dxg:GridColumn Binding="{Binding IMPORTO}" FieldName="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=Importo}" AllowEditing="False" >
            <dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                <dxe:TextEditSettings Mask="c" MaskType="Numeric" MaskCulture="eu" MaskUseAsDisplayFormat="True" />
            </dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
        </dxg:GridColumn>
    </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
    <dxg:GridControl.View>
        <dxg:TableView AllowPerPixelScrolling="True" AllowEditing="False" ShowGroupPanel="False" ShowAutoFilterRow="True" ShowTotalSummary="True"
                ShowFilterPanelMode="ShowAlways" SearchPanelFindFilter="Contains"  />
    </dxg:GridControl.View>
</dxg:GridControl>
```

and finally I call it in this way:

```
reportMonitorErogazioni report = new reportMonitorErogazioni();
report.DataSource = CustomGridControlService.GetAllFilteredAndSortedRows();
PrintHelper.ShowPrintPreview(MainWindow.thisW, report);
```

it seems to work well, but, like I said before, it gets always ALL the records. So, do you have any idea? Can I post something else useful for solve the problem?

Comment: Why don't you ask DevExpress support center about this? They seem to be trying hard there to answer any question about DevExpress components.

Comment: already done, I'm trying also here! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your answer i see that you need to obtain only **visible** rows from grid. If so, you should use traversing grid's rows(accessing rows one by one) rather than get rows from DataController directly.
To achieve this goal, you can use the [GridControl.GetRowHandleByVisibleIndex()](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfGridGridControl_GetRowHandleByVisibleIndextopic) method. Please refer to the [Obtaining Row Handles](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument6322) documentation article for more information.

The [Traversing Rows](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument6122) article demonstrates the possible code-snippet that implements this approach.

P.S. The [DevExpress Search Engine](https://search.devexpress.com/?q=get+visible+rows&p=T4%7cP4%7c107&d=15) can get all the answers faster than I do.)

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago i faced the same problem.
have a look at the following links.

[synchronize filtered data between the GridControl and ViewModel](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/KA18591)

[example provided by Devexpress Team](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E4173)